# Reasons why a cloudformation stack jumps back from DELETE_IN_PROGRESS to UPDATE_COMPLETED

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My cloud formation stack is in the state *UPDATE_COMPLETED*.

When I press "Delete" in the web console it shortly goes to *DELTE_IN_PROGRESS*, but as soon as I refresh the page it jumps back to *UPDATE_COMPLETED*.

What could be the reason for that and why doesn't aws at least give me some error message?

Comment: There's an "Events" tab in the CloudFormation Console that will tell you everything that it's doing/done.